# Opening file in Python 3.4.2 shell

Tags: python

I am using Python 3.4.2 on Windows 10 and am just getting into opening and read/writing to files from the Python shell

I did this test and got the following error message in spite of the fact that I had created the file beforehand (but not from the shell as that would not work either).

Can someone tell me what I haven't taken into consideration here because all my searches tell me this should work.

```
>>> import os
>>> helloFile = open('C:\\Users\\jennifer\\Hello.txt')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    helloFile = open('C:\\Users\\jennifer\\Hello.txt')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\jennifer\\Hello.txt'
```

I did as John Gordon suggested and removed .txt from the pathname and it still didn't work.

Here is the directory and path for the file:

C:\Users\jennifer\Desktop\Hello

Finally, it has opened and will be very aware of the need to call the complete path in the future! Thank you

Comment: It looks like that file really doesn't exist.  Can you show us a screenshot of a directory listing?

Comment: This is a wild guess, but perhaps the file is actually named `Hello.txt.txt`?  The Windows file explorer typically doesn't show file extensions, so if the file is actually being displayed as `Hello.txt`, then that's the _name_, and there is an _extension_ of `.txt` after that.

Comment: Your code doesn't have `Desktop` in the file path.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have backslashes (`\`) in the string and since backslashes in string literals mean that a special character is denoted (like `\n` for newline), you need to make clear that you want *verbatim* backslashes (as needed by Windows file paths).

For this you have two major options:

1. You can escape the backslashes with an additional backslash, i. e. effectively double each backslash: `'C:\\foo\\bar'`
2. You can prepend an `r` to the string to declare it a *regexp* string in which the special meaning of the backslash is suspended:  `r'C:\foo\bar'`.

There are more options but these are the two major ones used.

Beware, however, that the second option suffers a wart in the Python parser which prevents it to denote a backslash at the end of the string.  So if you ever want to have a string literal ending in a backslash (e. g. `C:\foo\bar\`), then you cannot use this option.

Comment: I don't think that is the answer here, as `\U`, `\j` and `\H` aren't special sequences.

Comment: Actually, in Python 3.6 the `\U` sequence gives me a syntax error because `sers` isn't a valid unicode escape sequence.  I'm not sure what Python 3.4 does.  Python 2.7 (the other installation I have) does what you expected, right.  But either way, code which works until you change `C:\Users` to `C:\new` should be changed anyway.

Comment: But still I think you are right.  The file just doesn't exist.  The error message indicates that quite clearly (assuming OP copy/pasted it exactly).

Answer (score 0):

You only need to put a '\' after the Drive, this is to avoid a unicode error. Code below is assuming you have already run Python in Powershell (Window's CMD).

Also if you want to read the file (i.e. print the contents in the CMD) you will need to make it readable by putting r before the filepath.

```
file =open(r,'C:\\Users\jennifer\Desktop\Hello.txt')
```

To print the contents:

```
for i in file:
    print(i)
```

Then hit Enter twice to get your output.